# Mapping option+k in Sublime Text — ST never sees it, what is eating it? (OS X)

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, macos-catalina, colemak

I realized that I never use any of the special characters I can get by holding down the option key, so I decided to map them to something more useful.

This initially went peachy, until I tried remapping opt+k (well, opt+e for me since I'm on colemak) and something seems to be eating that key. When I use the Key Codes app I can see that opt+k is recognized correctly.

[image]

But when I go into Sublime Text debug mode (`sublime.log_input(True)`), I can see that it never receives the opt+k. In this screenshot below you can see that every other key in the row is recognized by Sublime besides opt+e.

[image]

What could eat a key such that Sublime Text never sees it, but another mac app (Key Codes) does?

*[My .keylayout](https://pastebin.com/TtfYmGPj) and [ST keymap](https://pastebin.com/gLibaDLD) in case they are relevant*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by mapping the key directly to the output I wanted in the .keylayout file without using ST at all for the mapping.

```
...
<keyMap index="3">
    <key code="36" output="&#xD;" />
    <key code="40" output="else:&#xD;" />
    <key code="48" output="&#x9;" />
    ...
```